# the java code is not able to take last test case as input

Tags: java

Given a number K and string S of digits denoting a positive integer, build the largest number possible by performing swap operations on the digits of S atmost K times.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class competitive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=s.nextInt();
        while(t>0){
            t--;
            int n=s.nextInt();
            //taking input
            String number=s.next();

            int l=number.length();
            char[] num=new char[l];
            // spliting into char
            for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
                num[i] = number.charAt(i);
            }
            //converting into integer
            int[] nm=new int[l];
            for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
                nm[i]=Character.getNumericValue(num[i]);
            }
            int[] nm2=new int[l];
            for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
                nm2[i]=nm[i];
            }
            for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
                for(int j=i+1; j<l; j++){
                    if(nm[i]<nm[j]) {
                        int temp =nm[i];
                        nm[i]=nm[j];
                        nm[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            int x=0;

            //sorting

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<l; j++){
                    if(nm[i]==nm2[j] && j>x){
                        int temp=nm2[j];
                        nm2[j]=nm2[x];
                        nm2[x]=temp;
                        x++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
                System.out.print(nm2[i]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");

        }
    }
}
```

```
3
4
1234567
3
3435335
2
1034
```

it is not taking input 1034
how to clear the error.
i don't know but this error is coming for a long time and i am not able to figure out why

Comment: Did you debug? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Is the list of numbers the input, the output or the desired output? Please provide all of them and label them helpfully.

Comment: Running your code with the numbers as input I get output "7654321
5543333
4301" which seems to be a success, including the last test case. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: I would suggest putting print statements after each input to make sure that you are working with the numbers you think you are.

Comment: it just is not accepting last test case if you add another test case than all test case will be running but the last one and i tried with print statement  its not just accepting and taking last test case input and saving it